# Objective-c dynamically loading more UITableViewCells

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I am writing a iPhone app that calls a web service.  Let say the web service returns 1000 elements in the json object.  I don't want to load all 1000 of them since parsing can take some time.  What I would like to do is load the first 15 elements of the NSDictionary that I created from the json object and then when the user scrolls to the bottom of the tableview have a 16th row that says "load more....".  Since I already have all of the data stored in the NSDictionary object is there a way to break this up so that it returns the 15, then the user clicks "load more...." and it loads the next 15 and continues until there are no more elements in the NSDictionary?  I can present examples of my code but I am wondering if anyone has an example of how to accomplish this.  Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think a UITableView does this for you. Only the visible cells are ever constructed. Their memory is then swapped with the next rows as you scroll down. I don't see a point in re-inventing the wheel.

Also as a note, only the visible cells are "parsed" as you put it. It will not construct a cell for every item in your datasource on load.

Comment: Interesting, so when people put the load more... in their applications they are actually making a server call to get more results?  If that is the case maybe I just need to rework the Web Services to allow me to portion the results that I return.

Comment: Yes, jarod the web request is the expensive part so its often "Paginated"

Comment: Thanks, I think that answers it.  I will keep it this way for now and when I have to deal with a large amount of data such as an object with 1000 elements I can then consider implementing a new web service to break it up and go from there.  Right now I am running on a local server and testing against my local network and even returning 21000 elements it wasn't terribly slow so I think it may be fine to go live with this in its current state and then come out with an upgrade if the app becomes popular.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I hear you correctly I would say you just need a little tricky logic to get this working

I would simply maintain an index offset which I would multiply by the amount of rows you want to show at any time(15 in your case)

Your logic is to always return the amount of rows that you want to allow + 1 for the final. ex: return _indexOffset * 15 + 1; //for your numberOfRowsForSection

In your didSelectIndexPathOf you check if you're the last row:

```
if(indexPath.row == _indexOffset * 15)
{
     _indexOffset ++;
     [tableView reloadData];
}
```

This isn't an exact answer but I think it can get you started

Comment: I guess I understand that much, but I want to initially return 15 rows so if my numberOfRowsInSection is returning the [dictionary count] how would I dynamically change that number every time reloadData is called?